# Space after footer at the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css, footer, space

EDIT - PROBLEM SOLVED. Thanks for the help, everyone!

In this URL, the layout is how I want it to be (with all the overlapping images). However, at the bottom of the page is a huge gap, which I've had tremendous difficult getting rid of.

I've done a few searches and tried different methods with no success.

Would appreciate any help!

Comment: For future reference, don't use a URL as this will change in the future and people will not be able to see what you are talking about. Instead, post code-snippets that isolate the issue.

Comment: Your containter drops well below where your footer is... looks like maybe your divs/etc are out of whack

Comment: Sorry about that IcedDante—will do!

Answer (score 2):

In playing with your CSS using developer tools, it appears that the problem is that when you set the `top` property for `#absolute-container`, the gap is the space where the container would have been before being moved. I found that this works as a workaround: instead of setting the `top` property, set the `margin-top` of `#absolute-container` to `-723px`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jacob!

Cheers
T

Answer (score 1):

Very simply, it's because of this:

```
#absolute-container {top: -723px;}
```

A more complete answer is... your page is constructed wrong. Redo it in a simpler manner. I can't do it for you, but absolutely positioning things and moving them around the page like this is not good design.

Comment: Thanks, I agree. My HTML/CSS skills are not the best, so I used a few tutorials from the web—and I think in combining them, things got convoluted! I will work on cleaning the code up.

Thanks!

Comment: No worries :) You might like to look into a framework system like the 960-grid system (http://960.gs/). It will still require a little bit of learning to know how to use it, but it provides you with building blocks for your site to make the first stages much easier.